# Spark: configure the number of concurrent tasks per core

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running a spark job where tasks are not purely CPU-bound.
So I want spark to run more tasks concurrently that the number of available CPUs.

It's possible to assign more than 1 core to a task by setting `spark.task.cpus=2`

But decreasing the number of cores doesn't work this way. E.g. `spark.task.cpus=0.1` doesn't work.

Is it possible to run few tasks per core w/o manual parallelization?